# Send Hex Decimal over TCP / IP

Tags: vb.net, hex, client-server, tcpclient, tcp

Im Developing a client to send information to a specific server. And the server accept only a spesific data from the client. The Data is "163130303030323030fc". I have converted it into Ascii as

> "SYN10000200ü"

it works except "SYN". The "SYN" has to be converted to "16" to make it happen. But when I use the code `Encoding.Default.GetBytes("<SYN>10000200ü")` the result receive as

> 3c53594e3e3130303030323030fc

The code Im Using Is as follows ,

```
  Dim tcpClient As New System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient()
    Try
        tcpClient.Connect("192.168.18.6", 60010)
        Dim networkStream As NetworkStream = tcpClient.GetStream()
        If networkStream.CanWrite And networkStream.CanRead Then




            Dim sendBytes As Byte() = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("<SYN>10000200ü")
            networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length)

            Do
            Loop Until networkStream.DataAvailable
            Dim bytes(tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
            networkStream.Read(bytes, 0, CInt(tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize))
            Dim returndata As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes)
            TextBox1.Text &= returndata
            tcpClient.Close()
        Else
            If Not networkStream.CanRead Then
                tcpClient.Close()
            Else
                If Not networkStream.CanWrite Then
                    tcpClient.Close()
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
```

It ok if there's a way to send the data in hex without encording to ascii 
[image]

Your kind Consideration is highly appreciated !

Comment: Why do you send it as **"<SYN>..."** if it needs to be **"SYN..."**? It won't give you the right hexadecimal output if you don't type it correctly

Comment: Also, if you need to send it as a hexadecimal String, just send it as it is: `Encoding.Default.GetBytes("163130303030323030fc")`. There's no need to encode it to ASCII first.

Comment: Also, converting `163130303030323030fc` to text gives me: `10000200ü`.

Comment: @visualVincent ,SYN cannot be send directly digit 16 represent SYN, therefore if I send SYN the server code it self start to encord for each letter S,Y,L. Therefore I need to send a symbol correspond to 16 such as fc = ü

Comment: See my answer, should be your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the String to be sent as text, and not hex, the SYN-character would convert to char 22. Refer to the DEC/Decimal column in an [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Try doing this:

```
Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ChrW(22) & "10000200ü")
```

Else if it must be sent as HEX, just send the hex string as it is:

```
Encoding.Default.GetBytes("163130303030323030fc")
```

Comment: Thank you for the Guide, It Helped me to find the Answer, I have sent the request using default Encoding method and it works.... Thanks alot